# How to delete the first row from a .csv file?

Tags: r

I have 500 csv files in which first row of each file has the name of that file. I wish to exclude the file name from my data.

I have tried this but it is not working:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
myfiles = myfiles[-1, ]
```

Comment: Isn't there a `skip` argument in `read.delim`?

Comment: This code is not working                                                                                                            temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim(temp, skip = 1))

Comment: Sure it doesn't, you don't use `lapply` correctly. Please read help file.

Comment: If you have many files a faster option would be `fread` i.e. `library(data.table); lapply(temp, fread, skip=1L)`

Comment: option fread also not working

Comment: Did you install the `data.table` package?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a R question.  However, I thought I would suggest a Unix approach.  Unix will be much faster than R for this task and IMO it is the more natural tool.  If you have Windows you'll have to download cygwin.  This may be a headache, however, with only minimal knowledge, Unix is a very powerful tool. There are essentially two approaches to your problem:

#### First Approach

You can modify each file so that the first row is removed.  This means that your original .csv will no longer exist.

```
sed -i 1d *.csv
```

#### Second Approach

The first approach is problematic.  You might want to keep the original files.  If this is the case you need to remove the `-i` flag from the above code.  We will also need to use a for loop so we can name each of the new files.

```
for f in *.csv; do sed 1d $f > new_$f; done
```

A for loop in Unix is kinda like an R for loop, except `do` and `done` replace `{` and `}`.

Comment: Thanks..but I wish I could have got a R code for solving my problm